# Imcplicit conversion from string literal to unsigned int (bool)

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

When I run the below test program, I would have expected that the string literal matches the `std::string` constructor, instead the `bool` version is called. I wonder how this is covered in the standard and I sure don't understand why this is converted to a `bool`.
When I replace the `bool` with `[unsigned] int`it works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(bool value)
    {
        std::cout << "BOOL constructor: " << value << std::endl;
    }

    Test(std::string value)
    {
        std::cout << "string constructor: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test t0(true);
    Test t1(false);
    Test t2(2);
    Test t3("TEST1");

    std::string ts = "string";
    Test t4(ts);
}
```

## Output bool:

`BOOL constructor: 1
BOOL constructor: 0
BOOL constructor: 1
BOOL constructor: 1
string constructor: string`

## Output int:

`BOOL constructor: 1
BOOL constructor: 0
BOOL constructor: 2
string constructor: TEST1
string constructor: string`

Comment: I was trying to find this before posting, but didn't find it. :) Thx!